# Kendo Grid -> How to trigger custom method on Add click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to catch click on the "Add new record" button in Kendo Data Grid. 
I tried to find this in documentation but without luck (I found how to catch click on detail button).

How can i do it please?

I don't want to trigger adding new row but i want to redirect user on new page.

Thanks for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch the click on the "Add new record" button using the following code.

```
$('.k-header').on('click', '.k-grid-add', function() {
     alert("Forward to Stackoverflow");
     window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
$('.k-grid-add').on('click',function(){
    alert('Hi');
});
```